# Eclipse warns about a potential resource leak although I have a finally block which closes the outermost stream, what am I missing?

Tags: java, eclipse, streamreader, resource-leak

is there a reason Eclipse gives me the following resource leak warning: *Resource leak: 'br' is never closed"* ? The code I am talking about  is at the bottom of this post.

I thought my finally block had it all covered, my reasoning:

- res will only be null if the FileInputStream constructor threw and therefore nothing has to be closed
- res will be the inputstream if the InputStreamReader constructor throws (malformed encoding string for example) and then only the InputStream must be closed so ok
- etc...

So what am I missing? Or could this be an eclipse bug?

Kind regards!

S.

```
public static String fileToString(String fileName, String encoding) throws IOException {
    InputStream is;
    InputStreamReader isr;
    BufferedReader br;
    Closeable res = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        res = is;
        isr = new InputStreamReader(is, encoding);
        res = isr;
        br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        res = br;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
            builder.append(LS);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    } finally {
        if (res != null) {
            res.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems alright. I think eclipse just can`t analyze the code correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse probably just isn't understanding the shuffling you're doing with the `res` variable.

I recommend using the try-with-resources statement (available in Java 7 and up, so three and a half years now), it dramatically simplifies these sorts of chains:

```
public static String fileToString(String fileName, String encoding) throws IOException {

    try (
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, encoding);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr)
    ) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
            builder.append(LS);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

If you can't use try-with-resources, you probably want something like the Apache Commons [`IOUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) class's [`closeQuietly` methods](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#closeQuietly(java.io.Closeable...)) (either literally that one, or your own) rather than shuffling `res` around, which is awkward to read and I daresay prone to maintenance issues.

Using `IOUtils` might look like this:

```
public static String fileToString(String fileName, String encoding) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        isr = new InputStreamReader(is, encoding);
        br = new BufferedReader(isr)
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
            builder.append(LS);
        }
        br.close();
        return builder.toString();
    }
    finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(br, isr, is);
    }
}
```

Note how I use a normal `close` in the `try`, but then ensure cleanup in the `finally`.

But try-with-resources is the better answer, as it's more concise and hooks into the new(ish) "suppressed exceptions" stuff.

---

Side note: There's no reason for the `= null` initialization of `line`, you assign it on the next line.

Side note 2: If the file is likely to be of any size, consider finding out how big it is in advance and setting the capacity of the `StringBuilder` in the constructor. `StringBuilder`'s default capacity is 16, so a file of even a few hundred bytes involves several reallocations of `StringBuilder`'s internal buffer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (marked as accepted) and also for the related advice concerning try with resources, stringbuilders and the unnecessary null initialization!